# How to get an attribute of the first of a has_many association?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

`User` `has_many` `emails` and `Email` has an attribute `md5sum`. For a given user `@user` I'd like to display the [Gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/) image in `user#show`.

The following code in the template doesn't work:

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<%= @user.emails.first.md5sum %>" />
```

How can I get the `md5sum` of the first `email` for `@user` in the template?

**web/controllers/user_controller.ex**

```elixir
[...]
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = Repo.get!(User, id) |> Repo.preload([:emails])

  conn
  |> assign(:user, user)
  |> render("show.html")
end
[...]
```

**web/models/user.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Model

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    has_many :emails, MyApp.Email
[...]
```

**web/models/email.ex**

```elixir
defmodule MyApp.Email do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "emails" do
    field :value, :string
    field :md5sum, :string
    belongs_to :user, MyApp.User
[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `emails` will be a list of emails if there are any available.

The reason `<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<%= @user.emails.first.md5sum %>" />` doesn't work is because using `.` is used to access a property on a map. `emails` is a list.

You can use [hd/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.2/elixir/Kernel.html#hd/1) to get the first element of the list:

```
<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/<%= hd(@user.emails).md5sum %>"  />
```

This will error if the user has no emails associated though.

You may be better off defining a function in your view (or in another module that you import in your view):

```
def gravatar_url(user) do
  case user.emails do
    [email | _tail] -> "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{email.md5sum}"
    _               -> "some-default-avatar"
  end
end
```

You can then use this in your template:

```
<img src="<%= gravatar_url(@user) %>"  />
```